# power bi, building data models using datasets from multiple tenants

Tags: powerbi, reporting

here is a specific example:
i work for company A. i build a power bi data model using SQL query & it rests on service.

i want data from company B. assume they have a data model on service already. they are a different tenant.

can i connect to company B's data model as a dataflow, source, etc & use it in my data model assuming all necessary permissions are granted?

how do i accomplish this if not? what's the minimal architecture needed please?

thanks for clarifying. most sources on the net don't answer this specific example in my experience & i'm going around in circles with support to get this answered so any help would be appreciated. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerBI reports you can only connect to one SSAS Model data source at a time. You will need to use some kind of ETL process to pull the data from Company B SQL Server and stage it on Company A SQL Server and then make use of the data in the data model within Company A. I recommend you use SSIS and create a package with a data flow task to move the data you need.

Comment: thanks. the trouble is company B won't like giving remote access to internal database to external user, if i have understood solution correctly.

Comment: That's why you need to use SSIS. Connect as an internal user Company B creates for you and move the data to Company A. Possibly generate a csv using a flat file and then SFTP that file to a secure location. Download the csv from the SFTP at company A and import it. Company A doesn't have to have direct access but if you can't even get access to the data as in an account in Company B to access the said data then there's not much you can do.

Comment: yyup doesnt seem like much will be done. we get excel files anyhow sent in the email in different formats & we then use software that we calibrate to the  different formats to get back into a database from whence they essentially came. it seems very inefficient & roundabout. everyone has a database & everyone builds reports on top of that essentially. i was hoping we could rope those things together.